# python re match exact only one occurrence (no repeat Consecutive)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

i want a python re to match exact one occurrence of / . indeed if occurs more / such as // or /// re shouldn't match any of them.

for example below inputs must convert:

a/b -> a b

a//b -> a//b

a/// -> a///b

Comment: Use `r'^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$'` to match and then use `r'\1 \2'` for replacement

Answer (score 3):

You need (negative) lookarounds:

```
(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZCVmhZ/1)

This regex matches a single forward slash, but only if it's not preceeded or followed by another slash.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a regex with 2 capture groups:

```
r'^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8WTRIO/1)

This regex:

- `^`: Start
- `([^/]*)`: matches 0 or more characters that are not `/` and captures in group #1
- `/`: Match a `/`
- `([^/]*)`: matches 0 or more characters that are not `/` and captures in group #2
- `$`: End

**Code:**

```
import re
str = re.sub(r'^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$', r'\1 \2', str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern:

```
(?<=[a-z])\/(?=[a-z])
```

- `(?<=[a-z])` Positive lookbehind for letter.
- `\/` Match a `/`.
- `(?=[a-z])` Positive lookahead for letter.

Replacing matched `/` with empty string in `re.sub`.

In Python:

```
import re

string = ['a/b','a//b','a///b']
print(re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])\/(?=[a-z])',r' ',str(string)))
```

Prints:

```
['a b', 'a//b', 'a///b']
```